# Problemas en android 6.0 y posteriores

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
    String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
    String mcc = networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
Log.d("Tag=>", mcc);
```

Los permisos en el manifest estan habilitados, el logcat muestra lo siguiente:

> 01-31 13:17:15.787 4996-4996/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10317
>       01-31 13:17:15.787 4996-4996/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
>       01-31 13:17:15.791 4996-4996/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
>       01-31 13:17:15.800 4996-4996/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[1],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 SPD:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0006 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0004, [-1 -1 0 1 0 1]
>       01-31 13:17:15.801 4996-4996/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.israel.localizacion2 
>       01-31 13:17:15.804 4996-4996/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>       01-31 13:17:15.867 4996-4996/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
>       01-31 13:17:15.867 4996-4996/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
>       01-31 13:17:16.378 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.israel.localizacion2-1/lib/arm64
>       01-31 13:17:16.399 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ContextRelationMgrBrdg: loadKlass() : caller=com.samsung.android.bridge.multiscreen.common.ContextRelationManagerBridge.:28 android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication:833 
>       01-31 13:17:16.425 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
>       01-31 13:17:16.429 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>       01-31 13:17:16.555 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>       01-31 13:17:16.695 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.696 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.702 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.703 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.704 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.706 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.707 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.708 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.709 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>       01-31 13:17:16.746 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=77
>       01-31 13:17:16.748 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@5f843e3[MainActivity] touchMode=true
>       01-31 13:17:16.806 4996-5017/com.example.israel.localizacion2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>       01-31 13:17:16.806 4996-5017/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>       01-31 13:17:16.818 4996-5017/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.israel.localizacion2
>       01-31 13:17:16.822 4996-5017/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
>       01-31 13:17:16.856 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
>       01-31 13:17:16.869 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
>       01-31 13:17:16.869 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>       01-31 13:17:16.870 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>       01-31 13:17:16.891 4996-5011/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=84
>       01-31 13:17:30.825 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
>       01-31 13:17:30.827 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
>       01-31 13:17:30.832 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>       01-31 13:17:30.907 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
>       01-31 13:17:31.718 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
>       01-31 13:17:32.281 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
>       01-31 13:18:32.237 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>       01-31 13:18:32.251 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=87
>       01-31 13:18:32.251 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=84
>       01-31 13:18:33.870 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/ViewRootImpl@6c6d012[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
>       01-31 13:18:34.152 4996-4996/com.example.israel.localizacion2 D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=87

Pero no se observa nada en el `log.d`, este mismo código funciona en `lollipop`, que podría ser?, gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que solicitar permisos al usuario. Puedes leer de eso en este [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es-419)

A partir de Android 6.0 (nivel de API 23), los usuarios conceden permisos a las apps mientras se ejecutan, no cuando instalan la app.

Para que compruebes que es error de falta de permisos, puedes ir a `Configuracion -> Aplicaciones -> Tu aplicacion -> Permisos` y habilitar el permiso

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 problemas

1) Estas detectando si tienes o no permisos pero no los estas requiriendo.

2) El permiso que se debe requerir para usar para usar la clase `TelephonyManager` es:

```
Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Por lo tanto realiza esta modificación, agregando la petición de los mismos y el permiso `READ_PHONE_STATE` :

```
    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 12345;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);

        return;
    }
```

Recuerda agregar el permisos en tu AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```